# Algorithm to find prime numbers with odd digits in large range

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

Given a range of [1, 1000000000] we need to find prime numbers and all the digits of the prime number must be odd. (Example: 23 is not okay, 31 is okay)
If we go on by looping through each number and checking if it is prime etc, it is very slow. Is there a way to make this close to O(N) ?
I tried to eliminate as much as possible by looking at digits first. But after eliminating numbers with even digits the prime test is too slow.

- for all numbers in [1, N]
- check all digits, if any even digit, continue
- check primality (this step is very slow)

And the primality test should not be very complex (probabilistic etc. is not possible, it must be possible to implement in a few minutes). The one I use is:

```
    private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= n / 2; divisor++) {
            if (n % divisor == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return isPrime;
   }
```

Maybe there is a trick to ensure a quick primality test but I couldn't find. Any suggestions?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can also precalculate the results for the wanted range (or upload an already calculated prime table) and search in it. What should be described is your use case: are you just searching for an algorithm, or is this function needs to be called many times (such things)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check all milliard numbers. Generate all numbers with only odd digits -  there are at most 5^9~2 millions of them. Exclude those ending with 5 and not generate numbers divisible by 3 (in the moment of the last digit generation)

Then check these numbers for primality. Note that loop limit might be sqrt(n)

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/rEjhbU)

```
class Ideone
{
   static int oddcnt;

        public static void checkprime(int x) {
           for (int i=3; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i +=2)
              if ((x % i) == 0)
                 return;
             oddcnt++;
        }


    public static void genodd(int x, int curlen, int maxlen) {
        x *= 10;
        for (int i=1; i<10; i+=2) {
            int nx = x + i;
            checkprime(nx);
            if (curlen < maxlen)
                genodd(nx, curlen + 1, maxlen);
        } 
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

    genodd(0, 1, 8);
    System.out.println(oddcnt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are in order, you can optimize your isPrime function.

Here is a js sample version.

```js
var primes = [];
function checkDigits(n) {
 while(n > 1) {
  var d = n % 10;
  if ( d % 2 == 0) { return false; }
  n = parseInt(n/10,10);
 }
 return true;
}
function isPrime(n) {
    for(var i = 1; i < primes.length; i++) {
       if(n % primes[i] == 0) {
          return false;
       }
    }
    var lastPrime = primes.length > 2 ? primes[primes.length - 1] : 1; 
    var inc = 2;
    for(var i = lastPrime + inc; i < Math.sqrt(n); i += inc) {
       if(n % i == 0) {
           return false;
       }
    }
    primes.push(n);
    return true;
}

for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  if(checkDigits(i) && isPrime(i)) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is to run a Prime Sieve of Eratosthenes to find all the primes in the range (0; sqrt(1000000000)) - which is around (0, 31622) - and time complexity O(n*log(log(n))) where n=31622. We will need those prime for a faster primality test.

Then, just loop through each number with odd digits - there are 5^10 = 9765625 ~ 10000000 such numbers. You saved 1000 times compared to iterating through all number in the original range.

The primality test using the primes we found in step 1 can be fast, as you only need to check with primes < sqrt(n), and you already have the primes. Even for the largest number in the range which is 999999999, the number of candidate primes is just 3432.

---

The following is a Java implementation

```
public class Execute {
    private ArrayList<Long> primes = new ArrayList<>();

    @org.junit.Test
    public void findOddDecimalPrimes() {
        primeSieve(32000);
        System.out.println(primes.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < 9765625; i++) {
            String inBase5 = convertFromBaseToBase(i);
            long evenDec = convertToOddDecimal(inBase5);
            if (isPrime(evenDec)) {
                System.out.println(evenDec);
            }
        }
    }

    private String convertFromBaseToBase(long i) {
        return Long.toString(i, 5);
    }

    private long convertToOddDecimal(String str) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            s.append(1 + 2 * Integer.parseInt("" + str.charAt(i)));
        }
        return Long.parseLong(s.toString());
    }

    private boolean isPrime(long n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
            if (primes.get(i) * primes.get(i) > n) break;
            long divisor = n / primes.get(i);
            if (divisor * primes.get(i) == n) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * References: www.geeksforgeeks.org
     */
    private void primeSieve(int n)
    {
        // Create a boolean array "prime[0..n]" and initialize
        // all entries it as true. A value in prime[i] will
        // finally be false if i is Not a prime, else true.
        boolean prime[] = new boolean[n+1];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            prime[i] = true;

        for(int p = 2; p*p <=n; p++)
        {
            // If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a prime
            if(prime[p] == true)
            {
                // Update all multiples of p
                for(int i = p*p; i <= n; i += p)
                    prime[i] = false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < prime.length; i++) {
            if (prime[i]) this.primes.add(Long.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an open question in math and computer science in general.
In a nutshell no, there is no know way to solve that problem in O(1) to get your loop running in O(N) over the whole range.

If you solve that, dont tell anyone, and go get rich by breaking most of the encryptions today that use large prime numbers.

What you could do though, is make the loop over the devisor a bit smaller by useing sqrt(n).

That will bring that inner loop  down from O(N^2) to O(sqrt(N))

And the whole complexity from O(N^2) to O(N*sqrt(N))=O(N^(3/2))

Anotger optimization would be to check the odd digits first beforre doing the complex Prime calculation